# ToolStripLabel not updated with application settings using PropertyBinding

Tags: c#, winforms, toolstrip, toolstripitem

I probably have a very simple problem, but could not find a solution. I have a problem with the property binding to a ToolStripLabel. A Label is bound to COM port value in App.Config.

If I bind the property for a `System.Windows.Forms.Label` label, the update of Text-Property by changing the COM Port works fine as it is supposed to. But when the label is IN ToolStrip (`System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripLabel`), the label is not updated by changing the value for COM Port at runtime.
It will be changed only by new start of Application.

In the picture there is a current settings of `PropertyBinding` to `ApplicationSettings`.

I've already tried:

- Application.DoEvents()
- toolStrip.Update()
- toolStrip.Refresh()
- toolStrip.Invalidate()

Nothing makes difference.
Does anyone have an idea what the problem could be?

Greetings,
Sasha

[ApplicationSettings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d89jt.png)

[Label Properties Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXLRz.png)

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4k8i8.png)

Comment: I'm not absolutely sure, but you can try to change Binding.DataSourceUpdateMode for your binding to OnPropertyChanged. It can be done via (PropertiBinding) item's editor.

Comment: @Serg Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, the "Property Page" is not accessible in the Items Editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ToolStripLabel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstriplabel) Component doesn't implement DataBindings, as the Label Control does (that's why you can see a Label Control update its Text when the current setting is changed). When you add `PropertyBindings` to the `Text` property through the Designer, the Text is just set to the `Properties.Default` setting selected (you can see that in the `Designer.cs` file).

You can build your own ToolStripLabel that implements [IBindableComponent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.ibindablecomponent), decorate it with [ToolStripItemDesignerAvailability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.design.toolstripitemdesigneravailability) flags that allow the ToolStrip or StatusStrip to acknowledge the existence of this custom Component, so you can add it directly from the selection tool.

Add a `PropertyBinding` to the Text property and now, when the Setting changes, the Text is updated. You can see in the `Designer.cs` file that a  DataBinding has been added.

[image: Bindable ToolStripLabel]

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.Design;

[ToolStripItemDesignerAvailability(
    ToolStripItemDesignerAvailability.ToolStrip | 
    ToolStripItemDesignerAvailability.StatusStrip),
 ToolboxItem(false)
]
public class ToolStripDataLabel : ToolStripLabel, IBindableComponent
{
    private BindingContext m_Context;
    private ControlBindingsCollection m_Bindings;

    public ToolStripDataLabel() { }
    public ToolStripDataLabel(string text) : base(text) { }
    public ToolStripDataLabel(Image image) : base(image) { }
    public ToolStripDataLabel(string text, Image image) : base(text, image) { }

    // Add other constructors, if needed

    [Browsable(false)]
    public BindingContext BindingContext {
        get {
            if (m_Context == null) m_Context = new BindingContext();
            return m_Context;
        }
        set => m_Context = value;
    }

    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public ControlBindingsCollection DataBindings {
        get {
            if (m_Bindings == null) m_Bindings = new ControlBindingsCollection(this);
            return m_Bindings;
        }
    }
}
```